# windows-server can't access L2TP from outside network

Tags: active-directory, windows-server, radius, rras

Server 1 Lenovo:

- ADDS
- DNS
- NPAS (RADIUS)
- static IP

Server 2 dell:

- IIS
- RRAS / remote access
- static IP

Remote access makes an authentication with NPAS (RADIUS)
PPTP works intern and extern
L2TP only work intern.

I want to make a connection with L2TP using an extern public ip.

I have an extern IP from ISP what work with PPTP and L2TP, but L2TP only on Intern network.

Question: How can I access my L2TP from outside my network, I already portforward the IP and PORT.

I tried to turn off my firewall connection to test it the problem was solved. But it didn't.
I have portforwared port 1701 in my modem.
I tried something with NAT but with no results.